# Closing an activity from another class

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a question in Android during creating my google-maps application.

I've one activity as below

```
public class MapCallActivity extends MapActivity {
    classA class = new classA(this);
    classA.callMethod();
}
```

The `classA` is defined as below:

```
 public class classA{
   public classA(Context context){
   this.myContext = context;
 }

   void callMethod(){
      if (isFileValid) {
        <do_something...>;
      } else {
        <call_the_activity's finish() method>;
      }
   }
 }
```

Is there a way that I can do `<call_the_activity's finish() method>` so that the `MapCallActivity` closes?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
public class classA{
    public classA(Context context){
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    void callMethod(){
        if(isFileValid){

        }else{
            ((Activity)myContext).finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to cast any object to close it directly?

Comment: if other Class has the refrence of this Activity. it can.  But other Activity or Service Can not.

Comment: Thanks for that help. I've reframed the question so that it is more clearer now. Will your code still work in that?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this though... the system should take care of this for you. You should also check to see that `myContext` is not equal to null, in the case that the `Activity` has been destroyed already.

Comment: This line -> ((Activity)myContext).finish(); is what i have been looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can call the Activity's finish method from another class in Kotlin code.
It is working perfectly.

```
class DialogHelper(applicationContext: Context) {
   
 private var context = applicationContext

    fun showDialog() {
        var dialog: Dialog? = null
        val builder = Dialog.Builder(context)
            .content(R.string.your_string)
            .positiveButton(R.string.str_ok, listener = {
                (context as Activity).finish()
                dialog?.hide()
            })
        dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        dialog.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Kotlin code, the important part is: `(context as MyActivity).finish()`

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is to use a receiver within my activity and then trigger a broadcast from **class B**.
 **Class A** gets the broadcast and its **onReceive** handles the work. Say **finish();**

Comment: please add an example for better understanding. thanks

Answer (score 0):

this may be help u....

add this line where you want to finsh current activity
Java

**`((Activity)getContext()).finish();`**